# What is the difference between ping and nslookup in name resolution?

Tags: dns, ping, nslookup

I am trying to understand the differences in the behavior of `nslookup` and `ping` when resolving hostnames to IP addresses. My confusion is summarized by this snippet from my terminal:

```
lllamnyp@lllamnyp:~/.ssh$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.221.131
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

```
lllamnyp@lllamnyp:~/.ssh$ nslookup ingress-vpn.do.company.com
;; Got recursion not available from 192.168.221.131, trying next server
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find ingress-vpn.do.company.com: NXDOMAIN
```

```
lllamnyp@lllamnyp:~/.ssh$ nslookup ingress-vpn.do.company.com 192.168.221.131
Server:     192.168.221.131
Address:    192.168.221.131#53

Name:   ingress-vpn.do.company.com
Address: 192.168.234.130
```

```
lllamnyp@lllamnyp:~/.ssh$ ping ingress-vpn.do.company.com
PING ingress-vpn.do.company.com (192.168.234.130) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- ingress-vpn.do.company.com ping statistics ---
```

On request, here's the output for `dig` as well. It works:

```
lllamnyp@lllamnyp:~/.ssh$ dig ingress-vpn.do.company.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.14-Ubuntu <<>> ingress-vpn.do.company.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55351
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: fcfdf62ef4bf6a33 (echoed)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ingress-vpn.do.company.com.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ingress-vpn.do.company.com. 30  IN  A   192.168.234.130

;; Query time: 161 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.221.131#53(192.168.221.131)
;; WHEN: Wed Mar 10 12:10:14 MSK 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 97
```

I have observed with `strace` that ping reads `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, while `nslookup` does not, but I'm not well-versed on their internals.

Here are my questions:

- If the problem is a non-recursive server, why does `nslookup <HOSTNAME>` fail, but `nslookup <HOSTNAME> <DNS_SERVER_IP>` does not?
- If the problem is a non-recursive server, how does `ping` successfully resolve the IP, when `nslookup` cannot?
- What has recursion got to do with this anyway, when **192.168.221.131 is IP address of the authoritative nameserver for `do.company.com`?**
- Fundamentally, what's the difference between name resolution done by `ping` and by `nslookup`?

---

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and the nameserver at 192.168.221.131 is CoreDNS 1.6.

---

Extra details:

Incredibly, while doing nslookup in one tab of the terminal and observing tcpdump in another, I see this:

Nslookup:

```
$ nslookup ingress-vpn.do.company.com
;; Got recursion not available from 192.168.221.131, trying next server
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find ingress-vpn.do.company.com: NXDOMAIN
```

Tcpdump:

```
$ sudo tcpdump udp port 53 -i tun0 -n
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
12:24:12.419836 IP 10.1.1.2.57886 > 192.168.221.131.53: 12557+ A? ingress-vpn.do.company.com. (38)
12:24:12.432512 IP 192.168.221.131.53 > 10.1.1.2.57886: 12557*- 1/0/0 A 192.168.234.130 (74)
```

i.e `nslookup` receives the correct responses, but at that point has already given up.

Comment: Welcome, `192.168.221.131` is an *ip* not a *nameserver*.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity thanks, I have clarified, that 192.168.221.131 is the IP address of a nameserver. Let me know if I can improve the question in any other way.

Comment: How does `dig` behave in this case?

Comment: @muru `dig` works fine, added the output.

Comment: Short answer: Don't use nslookup. See https://jdebp.uk/FGA/nslookup-flaws.html.

Comment: @berndbausch that seems in line with my latest edit...

Comment: Appalling, isn't it? Capricious little tool with an attitude.

Answer (score 3):

> Fundamentally, what's the difference between name resolution done by ping and by nslookup?

`ping` can employ various different ways of getting an IP address, (all listed in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`), while `nslookup` only asks the designated nameserver.

Comment: Yes, and `nslookup` never consults `/etc/hosts`