# nslookup knows while ping doesn't know; how is this possible?

Tags: dns, ping, nslookup

How is this possible:

```
% nslookup heartbeat
Server:     192.168.10.1
Address:    192.168.10.1#53

Name:   heartbeat.mydomain.local.lan
Address: 192.168.33.6

% ping heartbeat.mydomain.local.lan
ping: cannot resolve heartbeat.mydomain.local.lan: Unknown host

% ping heartbeat                    
ping: cannot resolve heartbeat: Unknown host
```

Doesn't `ping` use the same source as `nslookup`?

---

Note, that pinging internet sites work

```
% ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (172.217.21.164): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.21.164: icmp_seq=0 ttl=119 time=24.846 ms
```

so don't suggest that name resolution for `ping` is just broken

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between ping and nslookup in name resolution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/638520/what-is-the-difference-between-ping-and-nslookup-in-name-resolution)

Comment: I don't see applicable answer there

Comment: “`ping` can employ various different ways of getting an IP address, (all listed in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`), while `nslookup` only asks the designated nameserver.” answers your question, “Doesn’t `ping` use the same source as `nslookup`?”

Comment: But it doesn't explain session transcript before. If this was due `ping` knew more sorces, it would find the name, while `nslookup` wouldn't. But here we see opposite situation.

Comment: It doesn’t say that `ping` knows *more* sources, it says that `ping` knows *different* sources. If those sources don’t happen to include the DNS server used by `nslookup`, then `ping` won’t find the same hosts as `nslookup`.

Comment: If ping would use incorrect (aka "different") sources it would be impossible to ping internet. But it is possible

Answer (score 3):

`nslookup` and `ping` don’t use the same mechanisms to resolve host names.

`nslookup` specifically issues DNS requests; by default, it contacts the name servers configured in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

`ping` resolves addresses using [`getaddrinfo`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html), which uses [Name Service Switch](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html), configured by `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. This can combine a variety of sources, including `/etc/hosts`, DNS etc.

If NSS isn’t configured to use the same resolvers as those configured in `/etc/resolv.conf`, `ping` can fail to resolve a host even though `nslookup` succeeds.

Comment: To be nit-picky, `ping` makes a call asking the kernel to resolve the host name, and the kernel uses the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to make calls into resolver libs/modules.  As you point out, if the kernel is not configured to use DNS, the programs that ask the kernel will have trouble.  A good way to test if the kernel can resolve a name is with the command `getent hosts host-name`.

Comment: @SottoVoce to be nit-picky, it’s not the kernel, it’s the C library ;-).

Comment: I see. But there should be other pissibilities, since pinging google works by name, i.e. `ping` can reach DNS server finally.

Comment: I didn’t say that `ping` in your case isn’t using DNS at all: “If NSS isn’t configured to use the same resolvers as those configured in `/etc/resolv.conf`, ping can fail to resolve a host even though nslookup succeeds.” Your `ping` is contacting resolvers, but not the same ones (or not all those) that `nslookup` is. Specifically, `ping` is not aware of whatever is resolving `local.lan` (possibly mDNS).